# Names for two Basic axioms for Propositional Logic

Tags: logic, terminology, propositional-calculus, axioms

Many axiom systems for propositional logic contain the following two axioms:

$1. (\phi_1\to(\phi_2\to\phi_1))$

$2. ((\phi_1\to(\phi_2\to\phi_3))\to((\phi_1\to\phi_2)\to(\phi_1\to\phi_3)))$

These two axioms are of interest in that they suffice to prove the Deduction Theorem.

I was wondering if there are any names for these axioms. On [Metamath](https://us.metamath.org/mpeuni/mmset.html#scaxioms) I see that the first one was referred to as the 'principle of simplification' by Russell and Whitehead.  The second one is listed there simply as 'Frege' ... it was one of the axioms in Frege's original axiom system, but Russell and Whitehead derived it from their own axioms. .. but apparently none of them gave this axiom a proper name.

Has anyone seen any other names for these?  Or if there really isn't much in the existing literature: can anyone think of some nice name! I must say that 1 doesn't strike me as a kind of 'simplification' .. maybe something more like 'conditionalization'. And in 2 I see a kind of 'embedded' or 'conditionalized' Modus Ponens. Anyway, I would be happy to hear your thoughts, thanks!!

Comment: A. N. Prior in Appendix II of his Formal Logic lists some names for common theorems/axioms.  He calls the equivalent of 1. 'Simp' and 2. 'Frege'.  I think I've seen 2. called 'distribution' or 'self-distribution' elsewhere, since it says that implication distributes over itself.  I like to call 1. 'recursive variable prefixing', since it implies that an arbitrary variable can get prefixed to any, arbitrary, theorem or axiom, when modus ponens is available, as it almost always is.

Comment: Maybe 2 is a sort of Cut...

Comment: I tend to think of them as $K$ and $S$, respectively, by comparison with the types of the $S$ and $K$ combinators in combinator calculus.

Answer (score 1):

In the speech *[Die Grundlagen der Mathematik](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-663-16102-8_1)*, delivered in 1927 and published the following year, David Hilbert calls the first one "Zufügen einer Voraussetzung", which is translated as "introduction of an assumption" in From Frege to Gödel: A Source Book in Mathematical Logic 1879-1931 edited by Jean van Heijenoort.

The other axioms are:

[image]

translated *ibidem* as "omission of an assumption", "interchange of an assumption", and "elimination of a proposition".

Departing from the names Hilbert gave to the axioms, I'd speculate that Hilbert might call it "Distribution einer Voraussetzung", i.e., "distribution of an assumption".

Answer (score 1):

When I learned them, my professor used the following names :

1. Affirmation of the consequent.
2. Self-distributivity of the implication.

Comment: I like the name for 1!