# What is the term for the dual of the Principle of Vacuous Truth?

Tags: logic, terminology

The Principle of Vacuous Truth might be defined by the tautology: $A \implies (\neg A \implies B)$.

**Q:** What is term for the principle defined by the tautology: $A \implies (B\implies A)$?

Comment: The first one is Explosion (aka Ex falso).

Comment: The second one is a sort of Weakening.

Comment: Your title and your body are asking two different things, or one uncertain thing and one more answerable thing.

Comment: 2) can be seen as Weakening (From $P$ to $P \lor Q$ .. but in conditional form), Simplification (from $P \land Q$ to $P$ ... but again, in conditional form), or Strengthening the Antecedent (We effectively change the antecedent for $A$ from $\top$ to $B$). In Existential Graphs it would correspond to Insertion. How about calling it Conditionalization?

Answer (score 0):

I have seen the first one called [Duns Scotus Law](https://us.metamath.org/mpeuni/pm2.21.html)

[I asked about the second one myself](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4613074/names-for-two-basic-axioms-for-propositional-logic)

Answer (score 0):

In the speech *[Die Grundlagen der Mathematik](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-663-16102-8_1)*, delivered in 1927 and published the following year, David Hilbert calls it "Zufügen einer Voraussetzung", which is translated as "introduction of an assumption" in *From Frege to Gödel: A Source Book in Mathematical Logic 1879-1931* edited by Jean van Heijenoort.

[image]

Comment: Aah, rolls off the tongue so easily! :P